# JQuery auto complete with utf8

Tags: php, jquery, utf-8, autocomplete

Hi i use JQuery auto complete in my program and my database use character set utf8 with collate utf8_persian_ci.
when i want fetch data from database using php code and show them in edit text i can see data in JSON with firebug but auto complete doesn't suggest any thing!
how can i fix auto complete problem with persian language?
this is my php code.

```
<?php
include "Connect.php";
$term = $_GET['term'];//retrieve the search term that autocomplete sends
$qstring = "SELECT pName as value,pID FROM patient WHERE pName LIKE '%".$term."%'";
$result = mysql_query($qstring, $connection);
$row_set = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))//loop through the retrieved values
{
$row_set['pName']=$row['value'];
$row_set['pID']=(int)$row['pID'];
}
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
echo json_encode($row_set);//format the array into json data
?>
```

what is jquery auto complete problem with utf8 and persian language?

Comment: I don't know what is wrong and fix it!

Comment: can you give output of json_encode($row_set);